# Developer tools doesn't show-up in google-chrome on my Ubuntu machine

Tags: google-chrome, tools

Google chrome browser on Ubuntu, doesn't show the Developer tools when I  press F12.

Comment: I have never seen that before. Can you perhaps describe what you might possibly done to cause Developer Tools to disappear?

Comment: Can you try to create a new Chrome profile and see if the developer tools are available?

Comment: What plugins do you have installed that might have changed the hot key?

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to show the Developer tools pane in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If the devtools are already opened (minimized or out of view) it won't show up with <kbd>F12</kbd>. I need to find it with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>.